# java server gives up on older clients whenever a new one joins

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

First of all i'd like to introduce my current code:

```
/**
 App.java:
**/
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2343);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on 2343");
        }

        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                try {
                    new Helper(clientSocket);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    clientSocket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    }
}


/**
 Helper.java:
**/
package org.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Helper extends Thread {

    public static BufferedReader br;
    public static BufferedWriter bw;
    public static String output = "";

    public Helper(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("user found");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                bw.write("set");
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println(br.readLine()+"\n"+getId());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Client Lost");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 Cli.java
**/
package org.example2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class Cli {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        BufferedWriter bw;
        Socket clientSocket;

        BufferedReader br;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        clientSocket = new Socket("laith.com.au", 2343);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        while(true){
            String input=br.readLine();
            bw.write(inFromUser.readLine());
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Second I will show the outputs:

App.java

```
user found
hello world
13
hello world
13
user found
hello world
14
hello world
14
hello world
13
Client Lost
Client Lost
```

Cli.java (no1 all user input)

```
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

Cli.java (no2 all user input)

```
hello world
hello world
```

Transcript:

I start App:

I start First instance of Cli: `user found`

I type "hello world" into Cli no1: `hello world` (newline) `13`

I type "hello world" into Cli no1 again: `hello world` (newline) `13`

I start Second instance of Cli: `user found`

I type "hello world" into Cli no2: `hello world` (newline) `14`

I type "hello world" into Cli no2 again: `hello world` (newline) `14`

I type "hello world" into Cli **no1**: `hello world` (newline) `13`

I type "hello world" into Cli no1 again:

I terminate Cli no1:

I terminate Cli no2: `Client Lost` (newline) `Client Lost`

Finally the question:

How come, whenever I add another client to connect to the server the older client is only able to send one more message before the server stops responding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `br` and `bw` in the `Helper` class are declared as `static`.

`static` means that the field is shared by all instances of the class.

As a result, when the second `Helper` instance is created for your second client, these shared `br` and `bw` get overwritten with reader and writer for this new connection => i.e. after  that both `Helper` threads read from and write to this new connection.

You see one more write from the old client because when `br` and `bw` are overwritten, the old `Helper` thread is already waiting inside `br.readLine()` for an incoming string from the first client.
The old `Helper` thread reads new values of `br` and `bw` only after the line arrives.